# How to check for 4-Color Black?

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, adobe-acrobat

I routinely work files in InDesign(a lot of the artwork is linked), which to my knowledge does not have the ability to preflight 4-color black. I've not had any luck in Acrobat pro either. I save my files as PDFs. I have a PDF that I KNOW has 4 color black but when I run "List rich black objects"...I'm not getting any errors. Ideally, I'd like to be able to run a check in InDesign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Generally just use the **Output Preview** (Separations Preview) In **Acrobat Pro**

Untick the Black plate and if you *still see* something that's *supposed* to be straight black it's wrong and needs correcting.

[image]

You can do the same thing in Illustrator.....

[image]

Or in InDesign ......

[image]

This way you can check as you work if there's a concern.

**Acrobat Pro** : View > Tools > Print Production > Output Preview

**Illustrator** : Window > Separations Preview 
*(Be certain to turn OFF the preview in Illustrator before saving anything for web... it messes with the web output)*

**InDesign** : Window > Output > Separations Preview

Answer (score 0):

That is a difficult situation because 4C blacks can be made with a variety of builds: (50, 50 , 50, 100), (30, 30, 30, 100), or a "Photoshop" black. Because of this it is probably hard for InDesign to search for it.

There are three things you can do that I can think of:

1. Turn on the appearance of rich black in Indesign so you can see it.
   [image]
2. Download an app that you add onto Acrobat to run the check, Enocus Pitstop has all types of checks that it can do for production/prepress needs. https://www.enfocus.com/en/products/pitstop-pro
3. Add "unnamed colors" to your swatch panel, delete that color and replace with 100% black. That is assuming that you are linking vector files. If it is a raster file, it cannot find/add the swatch.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: In response to Marc Edwards, you can pull up separations in InDesign to view live. Go to window>output>separations preview.

Answer (score 0):

One solution: You could print separations, so you can see all the plates for the entire document. This means each colour plate is printed as a separate greyscale page, mimicking how a printer would prepare their plates. It should help highlight issues with rich blacks.

You can do this without a printer, by installing the `Adobe PDF 9.0 PPD`.

There’s some more info here: [Print booklet to post script does not work](https://forums.adobe.com/message/8121624#8121624)